# Use touchesMoved on a scrollView without building a subclass?

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, jailbreak, theos, touchesmoved

I have a jailbreak tweak - everything is a long story, but what it's come down to is needing to use touchesMoved on a scroll-disabled scrollview. It's a tweak, so I can't subclass anything. What is the best thing to do?

Comment: You need to give us more than that.  What do you mean, "use `touchesMoved`"?  You want to hook it, so that you can have your code execute when the OS calls it?  Or, you want to manually call that method yourself?  What is the purpose of this, given that your scrolling is disabled?  Do you want to enable a scroll view that's disabled by the original developer?

Comment: I want to get touchesmoved working on a scrollview that apple made.